# Float:right messing up my centered text

Tags: css

When my centered text runs into a float, it uses the edge of the float as its new border instead of the edge of the page.

For example,

```
<div style="float:right; width:60px; height:60px; background-color:blue"></div>
    <h2 style="text-align:center">Section 1</h2>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation.
        </p>
    <h2 style="text-align:center">Section 2</h2>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation.
        </p>
</div>
```

How can I make both h2's line up?

Comment: what do u want .........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<h2 style="text-align:center;margin-left:60px">Section 1</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now define `h2 margin:0;`

as like this

```
h2{
margin:0;
}
```

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/z9jhkitY)***

Answer (score 0):

Add a `margin-right` and `margin-left` to the `h2`s that is large enough to make room for the float, see http://jsfiddle.net/3QRcn/1/.