# Center inline-block div in parent while ignoring floating elements

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center an inline `div` in its parent. The parent element also has a child `div` that floats to the right. Because of the right aligned `div`, my centered `div` is shifted to the left. I want to center the middle div regardless of the position/size of the floating one like the image below with the code provided.

[image]

```css
.parent {
    text-align: center;
}
.parent div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div> ... </div>
    <div style="float:right"> ... </div>
</div>
```

The current setup has both inner divs inside the parent but I'm assuming the right way is to have the right-aligned `div` be outside with an absolute position?

Also, I have multiple instances of the parent div on the same page.

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548358/how-does-one-have-centered-text-and-right-floating-text-on-the-same-line-when-e

Comment: Does your right div have a known/fixed width? Same for C and parent

Answer (score 25, accepted):

set the right div css

```
position:absolute;
right:0;
```

relative to the parent div

```
#parent {
position:relative;
}
```

Comment: this also requires setting parent's position to absolute

Comment: If the right div doesn't have a max width (or a known width), content could be partially hidden under the other element. @Bobo relative is sufficient

Comment: was also gonna answer, but would have been the same as this.  Did create a fiddle though:  http://jsfiddle.net/HjGrV/

Answer (score 4):

`position:absolute` is the only way

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/u4FWr/1/

```
.center {
    display:inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

**EDITED**

*not sure if this has already been suggested*

Or you can `absolute: position;` the right `div` instead

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/u4FWr/3/

```
.right {
    display:inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
}
```

Comment: is that the only way.? setting a left-margin to the middle div as same as the width of right div, then set middle div margin:auto.. is this a possible way.?

Comment: That's a possible way but I wouldn't recommend it. Another way would be to set the right div to position absolute and locate it right, without floating and then center the other div accordingly. See my edit.

Comment: ya and that what my answer is about.

Comment: So the first solution doesnt really work because for some reason, the parent div ends up with 0 height. see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kdaker/Kggnz/) . The second one works with the addition of 'position:relative' on the parent however Sobin already answered this before :) thank you though.

Comment: Yeah @SobinAugustine did answer it first, It sounds like the best solution for your needs.